# Script to switch php version

Tags: shell-script, php

i'm new with creating script command, i tried to make a script to switch php version , the script will take an input what version what i want to use (ex:`7.3`)

here's my current progress:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=${1?Error: no version given}

#this is so wrong
CURRENT_VERSION = php -v

a2dismod php+CURRENT_VERSION &&
a2enmod php+VERSION &&
service apache2 restart &&

update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php+VERSION &&
update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/php+VERSION &&
update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar+VERSION &&
echo "success"
```

I haven't run the script because i still don't know how to concat the command with the variable and get the current version number of the php version to disable it

---

**Update**

Edited script:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=${1?Error: no version given}
CURRENT_VERSION=$(php -r 'echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.".".PHP_MINOR_VERSION;')

a2dismod php"$CURRENT_VERSION" &&
a2enmod php"$VERSION" &&
service apache2 restart &&

update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php"$VERSION" &&
update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/php"$VERSION" &&
update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar"$VERSION" &&
echo "success"
```

i got the following error when i ran the script:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.3 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
```

Comment: If the code block is *exactly* how the script is written, then it's not going to work because the `CURRENT_VERSION` variable isn't getting assigned. It should be `CURRENT_VERSION=$(php -v)`. Afterwards, the variable is referred to as `$CURRENT_VERSION` - e.g. `update-alternatives --set php/usr/bin/php+$VERSION` or however the syntax needs to be

Comment: @Lawrence thanks for the suggestion, please check my updated question

Comment: Be careful, it's **parentheses** `$( ..... )` not curly braces `${ .... }`

Comment: @annahri thanks it doesn't show that error anymore, but it shows `ERROR: Module php7.3.14 does not exist!` i guess  i should remove the `.14`

Comment: You can use bash's parameter expansion. `${CURRENT_VERSION%.*}` to discard the last `.xx`

Comment: @annahri i've resolved it by using the php script, but now i got the following error `update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.3 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode`

Comment: @jojo That's not an error, that's telling you that 7.3 is now being used as the preferred php version.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by [Lawrence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566884/script-to-switch-php-version#comment1054159_566884) in the comment section, you should modify your script.

In your current script, `CURRENT_VERSION = php -v` it has some problem.

1. It should not have spaces after variable name, otherwise, shell will try to execute `CURRENT_VERSION` because it interprets it as a command instead of a variable declaration.
2. You must wrap your command either with `$( ... )` or back-ticks. If it's not wrapped, `CURRENT_VERSION` will be declared but empty then your command will be executed and outputs to `STDOUT`

It should be `CURRENT_VERSION=$(php -v)`, it will store the command output to `CURRENT_VERSION`. But you will have to do some tweak because `php -v` produces:

```bsh
PHP x.x.xx (cli) (built: DATE) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v.y.y.yy, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

You only need the version number instead of all above, right?

---

Also, you have to prepend to your variable calls with a dollar sign `$`, and maybe you don't need the `+`

```bsh
a2dismod php"$CURRENT_VERSION" &&
a2enmod php"$VERSION" &&
service apache2 restart &&

update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php"$VERSION" &&
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/php"$VERSION" &&
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar"$VERSION"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, please check my updated question

Comment: @jojo Thanks for the update, but you shouldn't edit your original question, instead, add your updates below your original one.